# Power BI Embedded UserID filtering

Tags: sql-server, crm, powerbi

I am looking to have a setup in Power BI where each Sales Rep should only see dashboards with their data (based on UserId or SalesRepCode)

Each Sales Manager should see data for their connected Sales Reps. We have a table that links Sales Reps to Managers.

On our web / mobile apps - on all queries we pass SubscriberId and UserId, so we can render just the data that a particular user should see.

How can we achieve this for individual user Dashboards in Power BI Embedded?  Access should be read-only with filter ability.